# Mouse Input in Linux Angstrom

Tags: linux, input, mouse

I am running a loop that needs to break if I press left button on a mouse. I have a touchscreen LCD that will display the c++ code I am running, and I want to be able to break the loop if I touch the LCD screen. Thank you